# C++ Matrix Multiplication Vector out_of_range Exception

Tags: c++, exception, matrix, vector

I am writing a C++ program to multiply matrices in the form of 2D vectors. The matrices have preset dimensions and contain randomly generated double values. For some reason that I cannot figure out, when I run the program an out_of_range exception is thrown:

> Exception thrown at 0x7620dae8 in MatMulSeq.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00b3eb20.
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in MatMulSeq.exe
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in MatMulSeq.exe
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

I attempted to use breakpoints to determine where the exception was thrown and it seems to be when `vec_b` is filled, but this could be wrong.

I basically copied the method for this program from other programs I found on the internet that were confirmed to work, so I'm not sure why mine is failing.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

double randNum()
{
    double min = 1.0;
    double max = 1000000.0;
    return ((1000000.0 - 1.0) * ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) + min);
}

int main()
{
    // Seed srand
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    // Matrix setup

    // # columns of 1st matrix must = # rows of 2nd matrix
    // Result will have same # rows as 1st and same # columns as 2nd
    int RowA = 50,
        ColA = 20,
        RowB = 20,
        ColB = 25,
        RowC = RowA,
        ColC = ColB;

    cout.precision(2);

    vector<vector<double>> vec_a;
    vec_a.resize(RowA);
    for (int i = 0; i < RowA; ++i)
        vec_a[i].resize(ColA);

    vector<vector<double>> vec_b;
    vec_b.resize(RowB);
    for (int i = 0; i < RowB; ++i)
        vec_a[i].resize(ColB);

    vector<vector<double>> vec_c;
    vec_c.resize(RowC);
    for (int i = 0; i < RowC; ++i)
        vec_c[i].resize(ColC);

    // Fill matrices a and b
    for (int i = 0; i < RowA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColA; j++)
        {
            vec_a.at(i).at(j) = randNum();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < RowB; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColB; j++)
        {
            vec_b.at(i).at(j) = randNum();
        }
    }

    // Fill matrix c by multiplying matrices a and b
    for (int i = 0; i < RowA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColB; j++)
        {
            vec_c.at(i).at(j) = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < RowB; k++)
            {
                vec_c.at(i).at(j) = vec_c.at(i).at(j) + (vec_a.at(i).at(k) * vec_b.at(k).at(j));
            }
        }
    }

    // Display
    for (int i = 0; i < RowA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColA; j++)
        {
            cout << fixed << vec_a.at(i).at(j) << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < RowB; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColB; j++)
        {
            cout << fixed << vec_b.at(i).at(j) << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < RowC; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColC; j++)
        {
            cout << fixed << vec_c.at(i).at(j) << endl;
        }
    }



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm sorry if I'm asking too much here but I've been stuck on this for hours and I really could use some guidance. Thanks

Comment: This is not what you asked, but you should learn how to use external libraries for such operations (matrix multiplication). It doesn't make sense to reinvent the wheel. Learn how to use the `dgemm` function in the lapack library, which will do the multiplication for you efficiently. http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f.html

Comment: Did you use the debugger?  It shouldn't have taken hours to pinpoint which one of those `at()` calls threw the exception.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie didn't really know how, I don't normally use C++ and Visual Studio. I just had to write this program for a class on parallel programming.

Comment: Every major (probably every compiler now) comes with a debugger, not just Visual Studio.  Secondly, if you read the [documentation to vector::at()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) you will see that it throws the very exception that's reported to you `std::out_of_range` if the index used goes out of bounds of the vector.

Comment: *I basically copied the method for this program from other programs I found on the internet that were confirmed to work, so I'm not sure why mine is failing.* -- So how do you know the worthiness of code you just copy from the Internet?  The code is badly written just in the fact of how the `vectors` are initialized.  You don't need to write a loop calling `resize` to initialize a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`.

Answer (score -1):

In

```
vector<vector<double>> vec_b;
vec_b.resize(RowB);
for (int i = 0; i < RowB; ++i)
    vec_a[i].resize(ColB);
```

you are resizing rows of vec_a, not vec_b, so the rows in vec_b are all empty.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot.

Comment: not sure why you were downvoted, if I was a high enough rep I'd upvote it. Thanks again.

Comment: @possum_pendulum No worries. If this answer helped, you can accept it by clicking the green tick next to it.

Comment: That entire 4 lines of code can be written using 1 line.  `vector<vector<double>> vec_b(RowB, std::vector<double>(ColB));`  Maybe that's why the downvote was given.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Possibly, I was just copying OP's code to fix the error, not condoning it. Good improvement suggestion, anyway.